# Macbook 7.1 (mid-2010): upgrade from 10.8 to 10.12

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade

I've tried several times to update my Macbook 7.1 (Macbook white mid-2010, 4GB ram)  from 10.8.5 to Sierra but the progress bar remains blocked after the first boot.

When booting into Verbose mode, here is what I obtain:[image: Boot into verbose mode]

After a while, I have other messages like:

```
SmartBattery: finished polling type 1
SmartBattery: finished polling type 4
SmartBattery: finished polling type 4
SmartBattery: finished polling type 2
SmartBattery: finished polling type 4
SmartBattery: finished polling type 4
```

Which seems to be the same issue than:
[Mac Sierra won't boot - SmartBattery: finished polling type 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260592/mac-sierra-wont-boot-smartbattery-finished-polling-type-4)

Comment: Boot into Verbose mode (hold `Cmd-V` while booting) and see where it stops.  You may need to photograph it or video it to see what messages/errors it generates.  However, to answer your question - no, you don't need an Internet connection to install OS X / macOS.  If you did, you'd get an error that indicated as much

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you do an in-place upgrade or did you wipe the drive, install 10.12 cleanly, then use Migration Assistant from a TM backup?  I would go with the latter as it's much less prone to incompatible kexts.

Comment: I did an in-place upgrade, indeed. Would you suggest to you use this [how-to](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clean-install-macos-sierra) to install and migrate cleanly?

Comment: That how-to looks fine.  The key is to wipe the drive and install macOS so it's like it just came from the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions were kindly given by Allan, I chose the "easiest" one:

- In recovery mode, access to Terminal
- In `/Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/System/Library/Extensions` directory, remove Huawei .kext files (using `rm -rf` command) or other non-essential kext files. It appears that, for some reason, many users had issues with Huawei kext files...
- After reboot, the installation was completed seamlessly, Sierra is finally installed.